# Vue.js how to render dynamic component?

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, components, vuejs3, builder

I'am building a `laravel` project with `Vue3`. The main concept is that i'm generating input attributes from the backend and i would like to render out these in Vue. Now i have 2 component. `FormComponent` that contains the basic `form` tags, `submit button`, form title, etc... The second is the `BaseInputComponent` that contains the basic `<input>` tag. In the future there will be more components for `options`, `checkboxes`, etc... What is the best way to render out these input components with binding from the `FormComponent`. Firstly i build html string with attributes from `php` like this: `'<base-input-component label="xyz"></base-input-component>'` but i cant render this out from `vue`. The another possible way is that i use `switch-case` in FormComponent and insert the right input, option, checkbox component. I would like to handle submit in `FormComponent`. The code is incomplete yet, first i want to render these component and I want ot reach their values.What will be the best solution for this?

```js
//This will be the first option json that comes from the backend, but i cant render these out from string.
{
  zip_code: '<base-input-component name="zip_code" label="Zip code"></base-input-component>',
  city: '<base-input-component name="city" label="City"></base-input-component>'
}


//This will be the second option json that comes from the backend
{
  zip_code: {
    name: 'zip_code',
    label: 'Zip code'
    placeholder: 'sadas',
    validation_rules: 'required|string',
    type: 'text'
  },
  city: {
    name: 'city',
    label: 'City'
    placeholder: 'sadas',
    validation_rules: 'required|string',
    type: 'text'
  }
}
```

> `BaseInputComponent`:

```js
<script>
    export default {
        name: "BaseInputComponent",
        props: {
            label: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            modelValue: {
                type: [String, Number],
                default: ''
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 p-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
            {{ label }}
        </label>
        <input :value="modelValue"
               @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
               class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do get your question clearly, I think what you need is `v-for`. See [Vue3 Documentation: List Rendering](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-template)

You don't need to send the whole HTML text like option 1 from backend, given that is uncessary, and option 1 will be involved to either `Element.appendChild()` in javaScript or `v-html` in Vue template (not secure).

You can simply use option 2 data, assuming currently you only have `name` and `label`, which should be Objects inside an Array:

```
data = [
  zip_code: {
    name: 'zip_code',
    label: 'Zip code'
  },
  city: {
    name: 'city',
    label: 'City'
  }
]
```

Then use `v-for` within your template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <base-input-component
      v-for="(item, index) in data"
      :key="index"
      :name="item.name"
      :label="item.label"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Equals to:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <base-input-component
      name="zip_code"
      label="Zip code"
    />
    <base-input-component
      name="city"
      label="City"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

That should render all dynamic `base-input-component` you want.